# Image.fromarray cannot be used with array.array

Tags: python, arrays, image, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and Pillow 4.0.0
I am trying to make a PIL Image from an array of values, see the simplified code below and I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'` when calling the `Image.fromarray()` function.

Why does this happen?
When PIL documentation says:
Creates an image memory from an object exporting the array interface (using the buffer protocol).
and array.array documentations says:
Array objects also implement the buffer interface, and may be used wherever bytes-like objects are supported...

```
from PIL import Image
from array import array

arr = array('B', [100, 150, 200, 250])
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
im.show()
```

Comment: If nothing else you can say `Image.fromarray(np.asarray(arr))`.

Comment: PIL's `fromarray()` works with objects that support the [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html). `array.array` objects support this. The array interface is something defined by the `numpy` module. IMO PIL/pillow should support both, especially the standard one defined and built-in to Python.

Answer (score 3):

The array interface is a NumPy concept: [ref](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html). Said differently, `Image.fromarray` can only operate on numpy arrays and not on Standard Python Library `array.array`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use  `array interface` ([using the buffer protocol](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer)), try this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

w, h = 512, 512
data = np.zeros((h, w, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        data[i][j] = [100, 150, 200, 250]

img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')

img.show()
```

You can read [An Introduction to the Python Buffer Protocol](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/05/introduction-to-the-python-buffer-protocol/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I already switched to NumPy and it works as expected. I already realized that the PIL function cannot know the image size from one dimension array which is stored array.array